# Kitchen water cooler not cooling water

Tags: water, kitchens

Water in the cooler stays at room temperature and is dispensed properly, but just does not get cold. When I plug it in, I hear a low hum. Not sure how to diagnose. Any tips? It is a basic model that has two taps, one for dispensing room temperature water, and the other should be dispensing cold water.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If it is working properly, most of the noise should be coming from the compressor (the large black round object at the bottom). Unfortunately it's hard to describe what a properly functioning compressor sounds like. An idea for diagnosis: does the sound change if you put ice water in the tank and dispense it? That would possibly tell whether there is a problem with the thermostat (I assume there is one) or the refrigeration.

Comment: @KevinReid I can give that a shot later today. So if there is ice water poured in the tank, then I assume the compressor should stop (after a "short time", which I dont know how long that would be), correct? And if it doesn't stop then like you said it could be the thermostat? Not sure what that would look like.

Comment: I don’t think ice in the tank will do anything usually the heat exchanger is inside the housing. The water in the tank or bottle is not normally cooled. The water would have to get down to the set point in the heat exchanger itself. Are the coils in the back warm at all? It may be low on refrigerant.

Comment: @EdBeal it has been unplugged for a few days. So if I turn it on, pour a lot of room temperature water in the tank, dispense some, then wait say an hour, I should expect the coils to be quite cold, correct? If so then you think it would be the low refrigerant? Or could it be something else obvious?

Comment: No those are the condensing coils they should be warm or slightly hot.